# Computing a characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help computing this characteristic polynomial. I tried myself to understand even the answer and I didn't manage.

Here's the characterstic polynomial:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        t & -1 & 0 & \cdots &&&&& 0\\
        0 & t & 0 & \cdots &&&&& 0\\
        \vdots & & \ddots \\
        &&&&&&&&  0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &&&&&  -1 \\
       -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots  & &&&&t\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Here's a picture:
[Picture (Before the charcteristic polynomial)](http://up408.siz.co.il/up1/dzzkyymzy3zi.png)

The answer is : $\Lambda^n +(-1)^{n+1}(-1)^{n-1}(-1) = \Lambda^n + (-1)^{2n+1} = \Lambda^n - 1$

Can anyone explain me how  ? I did try with using $C_1$ for the determinant. but it won't get the same result as I wrote up there.

Comment: I don't get the matrix. Is $t$ the same thing as $\Lambda$? If not, why isn't there any $t$ in the answer? The number $-1$ appears twice in the lower left corner, but nowhere in the upper right --- where do the $-1$s stop?

Comment: $ \Lambda = t $. I just prefer using $\Lambda$ when using eigenvalues. Also, look at the picture and you can easily write the characteristic polynomial on a paper. It's t's on the diagonal, and all the other elements get a minus in their value.

Comment: And yes, my characteristic polynomial is written wrong, so refrain from looking at it. Just build yours on a paper within 5seconds. EDIT: I've edited my characteristic polynomial now, it may be better now.

Comment: So now your matrix has a $-1$ in the $(1,2)$ position, and in the $(n-1,n)$ position, but a zero in the $(2,3)$ position?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yup. again, if u take 5 seconds to write the characteristic polynomial by using the picture I've provided you'll get it instantly.

Comment: I'm sorry, why can't you just write a description of the matrix entries so we can know what matrix you are talking about? Something like, entries are all zero except $(i,i)$-entry is $t$ for all $i$, and [whatever is the case]-entries are $-1$.

Comment: On the (i,i) entries t for all i, on (1,2) it's -1, on (n,1) it's -1, on (n-1,n) it's -1, all the others are zero.

Comment: So then the determinant is $t^{n-4}$ times the determinant of the $4\times4$ matrix you get when you delete all but the first and last two rows and columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the determinant, consider, e.g., using the Laplace expansion along the first column. With
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
t & -1 &        & \\
  & t  & -1 & \\
  &    & \ddots & \ddots \\
  &    &        & t & -1 \\
-1  &    &        & & t
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n},
$$
$$
\det(A)=t\det(A_{11})+(-1)(-1)^{n+1}\det(A_{n1}),
$$
where $A_{ij}$ is obtained from $A$ by removing the row $i$ and column $j$.
Also note, that the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrices $A_{11}$ and $A_{n1}$ are triangular so that their determinants are products of the diagonal entries. The matrices $A_{11}$ and $A_{n1}$ contain $t$ and $-1$ on the diagonal, respectively, so
$$
\det(A_{11})=t^{n-1}, \quad \det(A_{n1})=(-1)^{n-1}.
$$
Putting this together,
$$
\det(A)=t\cdot t^{n-1}+(-1)(-1)^{n+1}(-1)^{n-1}=t^n-1.
$$

Comment: Why did you write $(-1)(-1)^{n+1}$? How did you get that? I think you need to take $(-1)^{n}$ instead of that, no?

Comment: and the $det(A_{11}) = (-1)^{n-1}$, and $det(A_{n1}) = (-1)^{n-1}$

Comment: $(-1)$ is the entry $(n,1)$ in the matrix $A$, $(-1)^{n+1}$ is the sign in the Laplace expansion.

Comment: So after you take the entry $(-1)$ You're left with matrix $(n-1)x(n-1)$ and on its diagonal there are $-1$ ,which means it $(-1) * (-1)^{n-1}$ ?

Comment: $A_{11}$ is $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ upper triangular matrix with $t$ on the diagonal, hence $\det(A_{11})=t^{n-1}$; $A_{n1}$ is $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ lower triangular matrix with $-1$ on the diagonal, hence $\det(A_{11})=(-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Yes but you need to multiply it with the sign in the Laplace expansion $(-1)^{i+j}$, which for $i=n$ and $j=1$ gives $(-1)^{n+1}$. So for the second term: $\underbrace{(-1)}_{\text{matrix coefficient $a_{n1}$}}\times\underbrace{(-1)^{n+1}}_{\text{sign in the expansion}}\times\underbrace{(-1)^{n-1}}_{\text{determinant of $A_{n1}$}}$.

Comment: I'm blind. I see that now. Let me update you if I figured it out now.

Comment: Last question Pavel, We mupltiply $(-1)$ with $(-1)^{n+1}$ because we don't know if n is even number or not, so we need if the matrix was 4x4 we could know that it is $(-1) * (-1)^{4 + 1}$ which means it's $(-1)(-1) = 1$

Comment: It depends what "it" means. Anyway, the second term in the expression for $\det(A)$ will always be $-1$: $(-1)(-1)^{n+1}(-1)^{n-1}=(-1)^{1+n+1+n-1}=(-1)^{2n+1}=-1$ (note that $2n+1$ is odd for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: I got it now. We just can't decide if $n$ is an even number. Thus, we can't know if $(-1)$ will stay $(-1)$ or if it will change to $(1)$. Thus, we multiply $(-1)$ by $(-1)^{n+1}$ and then we obviously finish by multiplying it with $det(A_{n1})$

Comment: Well, we can decide whatever $n$ we want. But this does not change anything on the fact that the second term in the determinant will be $-1$ for any natural $n$ :)

Comment: Thank you very much Pavel. Much appreciated! That laplace expanation explanation was brilliant.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Btw, If we had the value 5 instead of -1, it would be $(5) * (-1)^{n+1} * (-1)^{n-1}$ right?

Comment: If you replaced *all* entries $-1$ in $A$ by some $\alpha$, then the determinant would be $t^n+(-1)^{n+1}\alpha^n$. Note that $(-1)^{n+1}$ is the sign in the expansion (remains the same), but $a_{n1}$ and $\det(A_{n1})$ change respectively to $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{n-1}$. Of course, if only $a_{n1}$ changed to $5$, then it would be correct.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the given matrix is a [Companion Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

(Please follow the above link and observe that your matrix has the transpose form,which is also mentioned in the said page)

Now it is easy to find that characteristic polynomial is $t^n+(-1)=t^n-1$

(Assuming that it is a $n\times n$ matrix)

Please rectify me if I am wrong.

Comment: It doesn't have to be hard solving it I know, and it looks like the companion matrix, but I really want to understand how he did the determinant on Column1 and got that  $t^n +(-1)^{n+1}*(-1)^{n-1}*(-1) $ . Thx